# Show img src from Window location

Tags: jquery, winjs, src, attr

I'm using WinJS and jquery to view img srcs.  I want to return the src of the only img on the current location.  I can return the location with this:

```
WinJS.Navigation.location
```

How can I grab the src attr from the img on returned location with jquery?

```
 var currmap = WinJS.Navigation.location;
 var mapsrc = $(currmap img).attr('src');
```

This gives me an unrecognized expression error.  I can't use the img id because it will be different everytime.

Comment: you should pass a selector string to jquery.

Comment: Searching for the id, img???  Do you have an example?